# Is the Cartesian product of irrationals disconnected in $\mathbb{R}^2$ disconnected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

If we consider $\mathbb{I}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$then is this set disconnected? My intuitive guess is that it would be since an uncountable number of elements is being removed. Due to the density of the irrationals and rationals in the real line, I would guess that the subs pace topology of $\mathbb{I}^2$ would be a bunch of singletons, although I'm not sure if my hunch is right on this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the result that $X \times Y$ is connected if and only if $X,Y$ are? Anyway, recall that projection (on the first coordinate) is continuous: if $\Bbb{I}^2$ were connected, then $\Bbb{I}$ would be connected as well.

Comment: @Crostul I did not.

Comment: @Crostul when looking at the projections, I see the issue with connectedness. Thanks!

Comment: The subspace topology is *not* a bunch of singletons. In fact, $\Bbb I^2$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb I$.

Comment: @TylerHG: OP is right that uncountably many points are removed, since for instance every vertical line with rational $x$ coordinate is removed.

Comment: @TylerHG I wasn't thinking. I realize now that it should have been countable instead of uncountable for my wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{I}^2=(\mathbb{I}^2\cap\{x<0\})\cup (\mathbb{I}^2\cap\{x>0\})$, so $\mathbb{I}^2$ is disconnected.